# Exported powerpoint presentation: chart fronts overlapping, ugly text

Tags: macos, pdf, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a powerpoint presentation with an excel chart embedded. The powerpoint file looks good, but if I export it to PDF, this is the result:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: How are you exporting it? Printing to PDF?

Comment: In Powerpoint for Mac: file -> export.

Comment: I tried to export a chart from PowerPoint for Mac 16.13 to PDF and there is no issue. Try to upgrade your PowerPoint for Mac app.